# Does linearRampToValueAtTime linearly ramp in decibels or literally linearly in sample values?

Tags: web-audio-api

When I call

```
myGainNode.gain.value = 0;
myGainNode.gain.linearRampToValueAtTime(1, currTime + 5000);
```

does the gain audioparam literally linearly ramp the gain coefficient from `0` to `1` in 5 seconds?

Or does it ramp in terms of decibels and instead ramp from some negligibly small value to `6.02dB` (equivalent to doubling the amplitudes of the audio) and linearly interpolate the decibel values along the way?

Comment: In general, is it possible to logarithmically ramp to a certain value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [per the specification](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#widl-AudioParam-linearRampToValueAtTime-void-float-value-double-endTime) `gain` is an ([a-rate](http://webaudio.github.io/web-audio-api/#a-rate)) AudioParam and does not have any specific implementation. So it will linearly ramp the coefficient.

(Currently) the only two ways to ramp parameter values are either linear or exponentially. If you would like to implement your own type of ramping(ie. logarithmically) you can use [`setValueCurveAtTime`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioParam.setValueCurveAtTime) to define your logarithmic curve.